# How to replace previous image with new image in QGrapicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

In Constructor, using QGraphicScene  I'm adding many widgets and one image using Qpixmap. when I want to replace only image. i'm able  replace the image but these widgets are not coming   ..`
QPixmap *bkgnd=new QPixmap(":/res/Clamp  Down - Pedistal Down - Arm Retracted - Complete.jpg");
m_bkImgScene.addPixmap(*bkgnd);

```
m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtForelinePsr);
m_txtForelinePsr.setPos(POS_FORELINEPSR);

m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtMechPump);
m_txtMechPump.setPos(POS_MECHPUMP);

m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtRoughLnPsr);
m_txtRoughLnPsr.setPos(POS_ROUGHLINEPSR);
m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtHeBartn);
m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtHeMfc);
m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtIonGfb);

m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtProBaratronfb);
m_txtProBaratronfb.setPos(POS_PROBARATRONFB);

m_bkImgScene.addItem(&m_txtChamberPsr);
m_mapTxtWxs[CHAMBERPRESSUREFEEDBACK] = &m_txtChamberPsr;
m_txtChamberPsr.setPos(POS_CHAMBERPSR);`
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example? What do you have so far?

Comment: for changing image on click event of button i'm just writing          m_bkImgScene.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/res/Clamp  Down - Pedistal Down - Arm Retracted - Complete.jpg"));

Answer (score 2):

```
mypixmap->load("secondimage_path");
mylabel->setPixmap(mypixmap);
```

Comment: its not working. I want to replace another image outside of the constructor.

Comment: This answers works for changing a QPixmap shown in a QLabel at runtime.

Comment: @sohitjain are you sure you are loading the image and setting it to the correct label? the solution i gave is general because you didin't show us any code so :) you just need to use it right

Comment: thanks . its working but now problem is widgets I defined in previous image are not coming in second image. so how can I solved it

Comment: you need to clarify a bit more

Comment: I used some widgets( check box pushbuttons   ) and labels  above the previous image. Than I replace the image and write same widgets and labels after image replace but its  not coming.

Comment: please check edited question .  and for changing image on click event of button i'm just writing    -           m_bkImgScene.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/res/Clamp Down - Pedistal Down - Arm Retracted - Complete.jpg"));